# How to noisily select k smallest elements of an array?

Tags: algorithm

So I wrote a function to find the k nodes of a graph that have the smallest degree.  It looks like this:

```
def smallestKNodes(G, k):
    leastK = []
    for i in range(G.GetMxNId()):
        # Produces an iterator to the node
        node = G.GetNI(i)
        for j in range(k):
            if j >= len(leastK):
                leastK.append(node)
                break
            elif node.GetDeg() < leastK[j].GetDeg():
                leastK.insert(j, node)
                leastK = leastK[0:k]
                break
    return leastK[0:k]
```

My problem is when all the nodes have the same degree, it selects the same nodes every time.  How can I make it so it takes all the nodes with zero degree or whatever and then selects k nodes randomly?

Stipulations:

(1) Suppose k = 7, then if there are 3 nodes with degree 0 and 10 nodes with degree 1, I would like to choose all the nodes with degree 0, but randomly choose 4 of the nodes with degree 1.

(2) If possible I don't want to visit any node twice because there might be too many nodes to fit into memory.  There might also be a very large number of nodes with minimum degree.  In some cases there might also be a very small number of nodes.

Comment: Change the `<` to a `<=` and, in the equality case, flip a coin to decide whether to swap or not.

Comment: I don't think that works; suppose we have the array [3, 4, 3] and k = 2.  Then we never want to swap the 3 with the 3, we would always want to push it behind the 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to do two passes, the first pass to discover the relevant degree you have to randomize, how many nodes of that degree to choose, and the total number of nodes with that degree. Then, do a second pass on your nodes, choosing only those with the desired degree at random.

To choose `k` nodes of `n` total so each node has a fair probability (`k/n`), loop over relevant nodes, and choose each one with probability 1, 1, ..., 1, k/(k+1), k/(k+2), ..., k/n. When choosing a node, if `k` nodes are already chosen, throw one of them away at random.

```
def randomNodesWithSpecificDegree(G, d, k, n):
    result = []
    examined = 0
    for i in range(G.GetMxNId()):
        # Produces an iterator to the node
        node = G.GetNI(i)
        if node.GetDeg() = d:
            examined = examined + 1
            if len(result) < k:
                result.append(node)
            elif random(0...1) < k / examined
                index = random(0...k-1)
                result[index] = node
    assert(examined = n)
    return result
```

This pseudo-code is good when `k` is small and `n` is big (seems your case).

Answer (score 2):

Store all the nodes which satisfy your condition and randomly pick `k` nodes from it. You can do the random pick by shuffling the array (e.g. [Fisher-Yates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), [`std::shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle), [`randperm`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html), etc.) and picking the first `k` nodes (for example).

Comment: I expect the number of nodes to be very very large.  Millions is probably an extreme lower bound.  All the nodes may not fit into memory.

Comment: "My problem is when all the nodes have the same degree, it selects the same nodes every time". Do you run `smallestKNodes` several times on the same graph?

Comment: Yeah, in my case k = 2 and I put an edge between the two vertices with the smallest degree.  So if there are 4 vertices, then I add edges (1, 2) and (3, 4).  But I want to add more than 2 edges, and I end up adding edge (1, 2) again, which doesn't work because (1, 2) is already in the graph.  I want there to be at least some chance of adding (1, 3) so that I can repeat the procedure if I get an undesirable outcome.

Comment: You already have determined which nodes fit your criteria. Do you have a means of sequentially addressing each one uniquely? If so, just pick a random set of values on the evenly distributed interval of index values.